# How to reload android sdk class at runtime

Tags: java, android, android-runtime, dexclassloader

Is it possible to load an android sdk class dynamically at runtime?
Let's say I want to reload the class `android.os.Debug` dynamically at runtime, is it possible to reload it dynamically.

I tried extending `ClassLoader` and android provided `DexClassLoader` but these require full file path of the class to load it into memory, I don't know where does android sdk class files resides in apk/dex.

```
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(dexPath, optimizedDirectory,librarySearchPath ,Parent);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am working on a POC project to harden android application security. The project assumes the runtime objects are not reliable (they can be tempered with by frameworks like frida), to solve this problem, I want to load/refresh all the crucial classes (the classes which are used to implement security).